# how to compile code from svn into jar file?

Tags: java, svn, compilation, htmlunit

I found HTMLUnit is useful for me,but the files are too old.
So I use `svn co https://htmlunit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/htmlunit htmlunit` to check the code,But I don't know how to use them.

Is there somebody can tell me how to compile them?

Comment: Generally, by using `javac` and `jar`.  But it's doubtful that anyone here is knowledgeable about the particulars of how this code base is built.  Why don't you ask the authors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you have very little knowledge of Subversion.

I could link you to lots of verbose documentation, but let's make it quick and easy: what you downloaded is the **whole repository**, containing lots of redundant code, majorly the three *canonical* directories `branches` `tags` `trunk`.

In order to obtain usable code, you either download a stable (tag) version or unstable version (trunk). Advantage of trunk over tag is that it mostly contains new features, but tags are generally stable.

Try to get the following URL: https://htmlunit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/htmlunit/tags/HtmlUnit-2.8/, then you could try `ant` to build (I'm no Java expert, does the package have an ant script?)

Comment: HtmlUnit can be built using `maven`, it seems -- because I see a pom.xml.

Comment: No, there's enough knowledge of Subversion there.  You're correct, the convention is /branches, /tags, /trunk, but Source Forge exposes a repository using exactly the URL that was posted.  You don't know much about Source Forge.

Comment: Actually, it is a `maven` build. Instructions on how to get and build the latest version are [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingLatestCode.html).

Comment: @duffymo: I know Sourceforge because I have several projects maintained there, and I do use Subversion. I meant that shisoft has little knowledge of SVN because anyone with little experience is supposed not to download the whole repository and believe to be able to run "make" on it. That's what the question looked like. You have misunderstood my answer, and it has nothing to do with SF (any provider will show the plain repo URL)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to take the detour of building it from sources yourself. The latest version is 2.8, and it's readily available from the Maven central repository. If you're not using a dependency manager, just grab the jar from here:

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit/2.8/

Answer (score 2):

Check out the projects instructions on how to get and build the latest version !
http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingLatestCode.html.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it ships as a collection of submodules, each with its own build system (some of them maven, some ant).

The [latest release](http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlunit/files/htmlunit/2.8/) dates back to August 2010, doesn't seem to be that old, but if you're aware of improvements you need which are available only in later versions I suggest you look at their [CI server](http://build.canoo.com/htmlunit/buildresults), which provides already the [artifacts](http://build.canoo.com/htmlunit/artifacts/) from the latest build.