# Create a JAR from an SVN repository

Tags: java, svn, maven, jar

I'm working on a project for school and I'm using an open source Java API I found online (http://www.jfugue.org/).  I coded most of my project, but I encountered a problem and it turns out it was a bug in the API.  They have since fixed it from what I can tell in the Google code base, however they have not made an updated JAR file available in quite some time.

I was able to checkout the latest version as read only (using Tortoise), but now I'm not sure what to do.  There is a pom.xml file in the folder, and from what I've been able to gather online this means it is a maven project.  Up until this morning, I have no experience with either subversion or maven.  I'm trying to generate a JAR using the latest revisions so that my project will work properly, but I have no idea how to go about that.  What are the proper steps to do this?

The Google code page is here: http://code.google.com/p/jfugue/source/checkout if someone could give me a specific description of steps to follow or at least point me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Note: providing my specific case was only to add clarity as I felt the original question wasn't specific enough as nothing came up on search engines. This question is in general asking: "How do you create a JAR from an SVN repository using a pom.xml file and maven?"

Comment: Have a look at [chocolatey.org](http://chocolatey.org) for maven installation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to compile code from svn into jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309667/how-to-compile-code-from-svn-into-jar-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a maven project install latest maven version from [here](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi).
Then go into the folder where the pom.xml is located and run:

```
mvn package
```

This will generate a jar file in the target folder of your checkout (target folder will be generated by maven).

Hopes this help.

Comment: installed maven and ran `mvn package`, looks like it worked, thanks!

Comment: just confirming that it worked perfectly, thanks again.

Comment: Please could you please help me build a jar from this source code github.com/upictec/org.json.me I tried lots of things and even installed maven, but I can't get the jar

Comment: Plesse open a new question for this. And provide more info like error messages or the steps you try.